# Nested operation in R. Is there a more elegant way?

Tags: r, nested

I am carrying on this recursive operation (convolution) in R by just nesting one function into the other like a Russian doll. The question is whether there is a more elegant way of doing this.

To begin with there is surely a better way to set up the following input vectors:

```
ones =   c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
twos =   c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
threes = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
fours =  c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
```

The actual line is:

`round(convolve(convolve(convolve(ones, rev(twos), type="open"), rev(threes), type="open"), rev(fours), type="open"))
[1] 1 1 2 3 5 6 6 8 8 8 6 6 5 3 2 1 1 0 0 0 0`

Comment: There is `Reduce()` in base R, and `reduce()` in `purrr`

Comment: @RichScriven The typo is now corrected. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(purrr)
data <- list(ones, twos, threes, fours)
round(reduce(data, ~ convolve(.x, rev(.y), type = "open")))
```

You can achieve the same with base `Reduce()`:

```
round(Reduce(f = function(x, y) convolve(x, rev(y), type = "open"), x = data))
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't say whether there is a better way to set up the function, but the `dplyr` package in R makes it possible to write the syntax a bit nicer:

```
library(dplyr)
ones %>% 
  convolve(rev(twos), type = "open") %>%
  convolve(rev(threes), type = "open") %>%
  convolve(rev(fours), type = "open") %>%
  round
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.